# What is the CDF of a non-central chi-squared distribution with odd k?

Tags: probability

Wikipedia shows a version of the CDF of the [non-central chi-squared distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) using the Marcum Q-function as a function of $k/2$. The Marcum-Q function, $Q_M$, as far as I can tell, can't deal with non-integer $M$. So, how do people deal with odd $k$? I'm hoping to create a CDF routine in Matlab. Ideally, I'd like an inverse CDF too, but I can iterate if it comes to that.

Comment: Do you just mean that Matlab's [`marcumq`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/marcumq.html) function does't handle non-integer values of `m`?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so.  I thought the equation for Marcum Q didn't even work with fractional M, but it looks like it does, though you'd need to be able to evaluate Bessel functions with very large negative fractional orders.  Matlab can do fractional Bessel orders, but not negative.